# iOS11 -touchesEnded method sometimes no longer called until view recreated

Tags: ios, ios11, touchesended

I have an App (since iOS6) with a self made gesture/tap detector using -touchesBegan and -touchesEnded methods. This detector worked flawlessly for years, but since recent iOS Versions the following happens occasionally:

**Sometimes at a random(?) point in time the GameView stops to receive -touchesEnded: until the view is discarded and recreated.**

In my case I need to recreate the view by starting a new game.

I override all 4 -touches* methods now and do not use gesture recognizers. The GameView has subviews that implement touches, but those keep working as expected. -touchesBegan just saves the starting point and time of the gesture, so -touchesCanceled and -touchesMoved do not need to do anything.

Is there any change in iOS10 or iOS11 where I could start the search for the reason this might fail? An XCode Interface Builder setting maybe?

Comment: I have the same problem.... very weird...

Comment: Check all 4 method names/signatures for typos and that you are not calling super. I think my problem resolved itself after some changes and fixing the empty -touchesCancelled: The sensitivity to missing overrides seems new.